# Omit or skip intervals of x-axis area in chart js

Tags: javascript, chart.js

Is it possible to basically omit / skip / hide certain parts / intervals of the x-axis in chart js?

E.g. skip / hide 100%-30000% and 41000-55000% (so not necessarily equal to tick values)

Ideally a "skip" marker "//" would be visible between the ticks surrounding a skipped interval.

[image]

Comment: is this a typo/ 410000-55000%? did you actually mean 40000-50000?

Comment: Given the intervals to be skipped, the given to chart js could be transformed by subtracting the cumulated lengths of the intervals left to the data point and add it when generating the tick labels. But this seems complicated and error prone.

Comment: I think the approach here would be build a custom scale that can be composed of other scales, which is no small feat, but would be a neat plugin. Something that lets you specify different scales for different ranges, perhaps. I got an idea on how to build it, but it's kinda outside the scope of an answer here.

Comment: Perhaps I'm a bit confused as to what exactly you're trying to achieve, but is it not possible to write a function that checks it there is any data in a certain interval and unset it from your data set if it's empty? Could you provide a small data sample?

Comment: @MartinM. Something in the spririt of this https://canvasjs.com/javascript-charts/chart-axis-scale-break/ but for the x-axis like this https://d2mvzyuse3lwjc.cloudfront.net/doc/en/Tutorial/images/Multiple_Axis_Breaks/Multiple_Axis_Breaks_01_2.png?v=47920 . This issue seems to be about that: https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/issues/6737